# Failing to register task definition due to Private repository credentials are not a supported authentication method for ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have a docker image that contains multiple containers, one of which is hosted on a private repo on docker hub. I am trying to deploy my image onto ECS, after hosting the image on ECR, but I am receiving the error:

Private repository credentials are not a supported authentication method for ECR

I have successfully authenticated with AWS.

```
  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      GIT_URL_INSTEAD_OF: "https://github.com/=git@github.com:"
      FORCE_COLOR: 1
      ECR_REGION: us-east-1
      ECS_REGION: us-east-2
    steps:

    - name: Download Task Definition
      id: download-artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: task-definition

    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      id: aws-login
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    - name: Rename task definition
      run: mv task-definition* task-definition.json

    - name: Login to ECR
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Deploy
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
      timeout-minutes: 10
      with:
        task-definition: task-definition.json
        service: glean-payments-dev
        cluster: fargate
        wait-for-service-stability: true
```

The AWS Documentation seems to indicate that it should use the IAM role that I am authenticating with to pull from ECR which is why I'm confused as to why it's attempting to get the image with private repository credentials.

Comment: Does this private repo image you were talking now exists in  ECR ?

Comment: After logging into ECR, when are you actually building and pushing your image to ECR? You seem to skip uploading to ECR and move directly to deploying your new task definition. See the build-image step in the example here https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition for reference